# keeping the primery key value in web application form for updation

Tags: php, oop, web-applications

i'm developing a php web application.

i'm bit curious about how people store object's primary key value in the web form when they retrieve the object so that they can update the relevant record by refering the same record using the retrieved key?

for eg. i retrieve a employee record of pk_id=10. when user do changes for the object we need to update the object of pk_id 10. so i need to store the pk_id in the form.

i thought of storing the value in a hidden input field. will this be a problem.

how to professional people does this?

rgds
Rifky

Comment: This is not a big problem, in other way You can store pk_id into session if You don't want put it into hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways - the ones identified by @marvin (i.e. client side), and within the session.

If you use client side identification, please be very, very careful. In your example, it would be trivially easy for someone to set their salary to a million dollars if they knew their primary key. @Thomas Hudspith-Tatham says this is unlikely - I disagree, especially with a public facing website. In the early days of the interwebs, there were several cases of ecommerce stores having to honour orders for high-end products at $0.01, because the application used client-side mechanisms for transferring data between pages.

Incidentally, when modifying data, it's good form to use POST, rather than GET - so a hidden field is stylistically better than a URL parameter.

Using sessions is a bit of a pain - you have to worry about load balancing and cookies expiring, but it's far harder for an attacker to change data you don't want them to change.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden input field is fine and a good solution.

Storing it in the session is also an option but if you're using the session a lot already you may as well use the hidden input, a session is almost the most secure option though.

One possible problem is that someone may change the value in their html form's hidden input before submitting the form; it's very unlikely though.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways:

- Use `hidden input`, that's what they are for.
- You can carry the id in the get field for update url.(like
  `update.php?pk_id=17`) So when you post the form to itself, you can still 
  get the id.
- You can store id in the session, if you want to hide it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You are right. Storing the primary key id in a hidden field is a good idea. You can also pass the same from URL if you like. (Get Parameter)

Comment: -1 for GET parameter. It can lead to pretty undesirable situation.

Comment: I am not aware of that undesirable situation. I am new to this. Can you please explain what kind of undesirable situation are you talking about ?

Comment: someone may change the url themselves or use an old url by accident.  you're giving a lot of control to your users and they can also act very maliciously

Comment: suppose the object id is 10. I put 1 in the URL. what will happen? It will update the other objects information. Putting it in a session or hidden form input is the general practice.